# How to Print 64-bit Value in GDB

Tags: gcc, gdb

If I start a gdb session and type:

```
(gdb) p/x 1024*1024*1024*2
$2 = 0x80000000
```

But if I cross the 32 bit threshold I get:

```
(gdb) p/x 1024*1024*1024*4
$3 = 0x0
```

How does one display the entire 64 bit value in gdb?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to Yaniv's answer, you can use the `ll` suffix on one of the numbers (just one `l` may work depending on your system):

```
(gdb) p/x 1024*1024*1024*4ll
$2 = 0x100000000
```

If you need to do unsigned arithmetic, you can of course use `ull`.

If you want to print *memory contents* as 64-bit values with the x command instead, you can use the `g` size modifier:

```
(gdb) x/8xg  
0x7fffffffe008: 0x0000000000400e44  0x00007ffff7fe3000
0x7fffffffe018: 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffe028: 0x0000000000f0b5ff  0x00000000000000c2
0x7fffffffe038: 0x0000000000000100  0x0000000000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the value:

```
(gdb) p/x (unsigned long long) 1024*1024*1024*4
$1 = 0x100000000
```

Comment: I hadn't tried casting to long long since I was on a 64bit system I though it would default long to be 64bit. Thanks! +1

Comment: @Whome Actually, on my system, `long` *does* default to 64-bit. I guess the only guarantee that we get at least 64 bits is to use `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

in my gdb script. I used a gdb-script file, in order to reproduce the debugging process by `gdb bin -x gdb.txt`, so `printf` is used:

```
printf "0x%llx\n", $rax
```

works.

```
pwndbg> printf "0x%llx\n", $rax
0x7ffff77c0068
```